# What does 192.168.1.1 /4 mean?

Tags: ip, subnet

What does 192.168.1.1 /4 mean?
Is there a calculator that translates this kind of notation to a list of IP addresses? For that matter any type of notation so that it would be easy and quick in the future.

Anybody can give a short answer so I wouldn't need to study the whole wiki page?

thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cidr+calculator

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the 192.168.1.1 address is associated with a 240.0.0.0 mask.

You have to think binary to understand that. In binary your IP address would be:
11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001

In the same way `/4` represent the number of "1" bits in the mask.
So here the mask is 11110000.00000000.00000000.00000000 (which is 240.0.0.0 in decimal)

/8 would be 11111111.00000000.00000000.00000000

/24 would be 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 (this is a very commonly used mask)

So here :

**1100** *0000.10101000.00000001.00000001* (your IP)

**1111** *0000.00000000.00000000.00000000* (your mask)

That means that what is written in strong is a network, and what is written in emphasis is a sub-network.
So every device with an IP starting with "1100" would be in the same local sub-network.
But an IP starting with "1110" or anything different than "1100" will not be in the same sub-network, and will not be able to communicate directly with an IP starting with "1100".